# Slide-out menu with CSS transitions

Tags: css, transition

I have a vertical menu that needs some sub-menus. I can accomplish a decent-looking one just by putting a `ul` tag inside the link I want to expand and absolute-positioning it on hover, with `display:none` when it's inactive. But I'd like to make it slide out, and I haven't had any luck doing so. I have this basic markup:

```
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link Text</a></li>
    <li class="more">
      <a href="">Base</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Sublink"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</aisde>
```

The `aside` tag is itself a secondary navigation menu, the main one is in my header. It is `position:fixed` for easy access while scrolling.

The `ul` tag inside of `<li class="more">` is absolutely positioned, anchored to -1px on the top and `width:154px`, and on hover it becomes `display:block; left:154px` (of course, it is `display:none` when inactive). I have tried transitioning the `left` property, but it does not change anything, it acts as if my transition weren't even there.

Comment: can you show your css as well ?

Comment: You can't transition the display property. You can transition opacity and height though.